# How to mount a remote vob in dynamic view on clearcase

Tags: clearcase, mount, cleartool, vob

Trying to mount a remote vob on my dynamic view but getting Error

when applying command **cleartool lsvob** getting this vob in the list and it is public

command i am trying is **cleartool mount \clinical**

> cleartool: Error: The VOB storage directory "\servername\vob_store\clinical.vbs" was not found.

Answer (score 0):

The simple check is to make sure the [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) is accessible.

For Windows, its **[vob global path](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_props_vob.htm)** (vob storage directory) should start with `\\`, not `\`.
(The vob *tag* will start with a `\` though: `\clinical` is fine)

```
dir \\servername\vob_store\clinical.vbs
```

If its path starts with `\`, the vob needs to be re-declared with the right UNC path.
I would say unregister/rmtag, and re-rag with the right global path, as [in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234135), or using the `-replace` option:

```
cleartool register –vob –replace \\vobsvr-new\vobstg\libpub.vbs
cleartool mktag –vob –replace –tag \libpub \\vobsvr-new\vobstg\libpub.vbs
```

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

That confirms the issue: the user must not be in the ClearCase_Users group.

Comment: @akshayjain ok, but can you do a dir of that path?

Comment: its not my local machine how could I do a dir on that path.

Comment: i tired the **pushd //globalpath** command getting error `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

Comment: @akshayjain I meant: dir, a simple dir. Not pushd. dir